# Selenium / FlashSelenium calling the wrong methods?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, selenium

Seems like sometimes when Selenium should call a certain method, it instead calls another, as pointed out by the following log:

> 14:57:18.328 INFO - Command request:
>   getEval[this.browserbot.findElement("someElement").doFlexClick('someIdOfAButton','');,
>   ] on session
>   21708b0a4a154ebc96c9720c14578e74
>
> 14:57:18.343 INFO - Got result:
>   OK,Error: Cannot type text into
>   someIdOfAButton on session
>   21708b0a4a154ebc96c9720c14578e74

I've tried both Selenium server 1.0.3 and the 2.0 alpha 7 versions, they both display this behaviour. FlashSelenium is involved so I'm not sure where along the way lies the bug. Furthermore it's hard to reproduce as it doesn't happen only for some methods, and doesn't always happen.

I've tried searching for issues similar to these but couldn't find any remotely similar... Anyone experienced the same behavior? And if so, is there a fix for it?

**Edit:** I doubt FlashSelenium is at fault for this, as the log tells that the command arrives correctly at the server... But I can't seem to be able to follow the path of execution from the moment the Selenium server gets the command and passes over to the browser, to the moment where it gets the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for this is apparently making sure you expose only one JavaScript method through ExternalInterface in Flex. That way Selenium has no way of getting confused about which one to call...